# Drawing scream bubble on Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am in the process of drawing speech bubbles on canvas. So far I has completed speech, square, thought bubble. I am having difficulty drawing scream bubble on canvas.
I was able to draw scream bubble on canvas by trial and error, I got its coordinates. But I want my bubble to stretch when I increase my canvas width and height. I was able to get this functionality for rest of the bubbles but not for scream speech bubble.

Do any have some idea on how to do it?

Below is my code for drawing scream bubble: (value of `n` is 300)
I know the values I am passing to `drawPath.lineTo()` are bit confusing I was trying out to make it responsive.

My apologies if it gives you guys difficulty while reading it.
Thanks in advance :)

```
        drawPath.moveTo(getWidth()-(n+50),getHeight()-100-150);

        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n),getHeight()-100-145);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-50),getHeight()-100-190);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-100),getHeight()-100-160);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-150),getHeight()-100-190);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-200),getHeight()-100-145);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-250),getHeight()-100-150);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-255),getHeight()-100-100);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-n),getHeight()-100-80);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-255),getHeight()-100-70);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-260),getHeight()-100-10);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-200),getHeight()-100-15);

        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-150),getHeight()-100+25);

        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-100),getHeight()-100);

        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n-50),getHeight()-100+25);

        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n),getHeight()-100-10);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n+50),getHeight()-100-5);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n+50),getHeight()-100-55);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n+100),getHeight()-100-75);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n+50),getHeight()-100-95);
        drawPath.lineTo(getWidth()-(n+50),getHeight()-100-150);
```

For those who dont know how scream bubble looks, below is an example:

### Example

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion: put width and height values to local variables intead of calling getWidth() and getHeight()

Comment: u mean if getWidth() value is 400, I should pass 400 instead of getWidth() ?

Comment: just to speed up the drawing, declare a local variable width = getWidth() and use it inside .lineto() intead of calling getWidth()

Comment: what is "scream bubble" ? any image?

Comment: okay thanks :) but I want it to be responsive when I increase canvas width and height ?

Comment: @pskink i have added the link in my question

Comment: the image with spikes